# jQuery animation issue chrome vs mozilla

Tags: jquery, animation

I am having an issue with a div that I am trying to animate. In mozilla when I run the code below I get an animation of the #nav div from the bottom of the page to about the top of the page. When I run the same code in chrome or safari it jumps to the top of the browser window and animates down 52px. Do you know why this is happening?

```
 $("#nav").animate({'top': 52}, 2000);
```

The #nav div

```
position:absolute;
bottom:-70px;
```

1st onclick event triggers its partial appearance from the bottom of the page. 2nd onclick triggers it to move from the bottom of the page to the top of the page.

Comment: Do you have a `top` set on your element initially?

Comment: No. Let me try setting a top.

Comment: I have it set to position: absolute;  bottom: -70px; because it animates up from the bottom of the page on an onclick.

Comment: Then another onlcick event trigger its animation from bottom of the page to the top.

Comment: So you have positioned the element using bottom but are then animating top?  I would think that might be the issue.

Comment: Do you have any idea why mozilla is treating it differently?

Comment: It's possible firefox returns the calculated top whereas chrome returns nothing when top is not set.

Comment: @ocat My guess was right.  See the fiddle in my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be due to the fact that you are animating the `top` of an element which did not have a `top` set.  You can work around this by setting the `top` right before the animate:

```
var $this = $("#nav");

$this.css("top", $this.position().top);
$(this).animate({"top": 0}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zmrC5/

**EDIT:** The difference is due to the different results the browsers return when checking the `top` value of an element which does not have top set.  You can see this from this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zmrC5/1/

Chrome will return "auto" whereas firefox returns the calculated top value.

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle for validation.